# ui:composition hides h:form parameter enctype

Tags: jsf, facelets, multipartform-data, composition

I have a problem with `ui:composition` and `h:form` parameter `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

When `h:form` is nested in `ui:compostion`, `h:inputFile` throws:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: The request content-type is not a multipart/form-data
```

When I place `h:inputFile` on JSF page without `ui:composition` it works fine.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
<h:head>
    <title>Power Consumption</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <ui:composition template="./resources/templates/dashboardTemplate.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="content">
            <h:form id="pcForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <h2>
                    Power Consumption
                </h2>
                <br/>
                <h:outputLabel value="Upload CSV"/>
                <h:inputFile id="file" value="#{powerConsumption.file}"/>
                <h:commandButton value="Upload" action="#{powerConsumption.upload()}"/>
                <br/>
                <h:inputTextarea value="#{powerConsumption.fileContent}" rows="30" cols="80"/>
            </h:form>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
```

dashboardTemplate.xhtml

```
<h:body>

    <div id="top">
        <ui:insert name="top">Welcome to Information Resource Manager 2</ui:insert>
    </div>

    <div id="content" class="center_content">
        <ui:insert name="content">Content</ui:insert>
    </div>

    <div id="bottom">
        <ui:insert name="bottom">Powered by Java</ui:insert>
    </div>

</h:body>
```

Comment: So, `dashboardTemplate.xhtml` has another `<h:form>` around the `<ui:insert>`? And you're thus essentially nesting forms in each other? This is illegal in HTML. This problem is not caused by JSF/Facelets. You'd better have shown the final JSF component tree composition in a single XHTML file without any `<ui:composition>`, `<ui:define>`, etc nuisance from templating. This mistake could then have been pointed out sooner.

Comment: By the way, `prependId="false"` is bad practice. Get rid of it.

Comment: All right, when I got rid of h:form in the template h:inputFile stopped throwing exception, but I get warnings The form component needs to have a UIForm in its ancestry. Suggestion: enclose the necessary components within <h:form>

Comment: Just put those in a form. You only shouldn't nest forms.

Answer (score 1):

> *When h:form is nested in ui:compostion, h:inputFile throws*:
>
> > javax.servlet.ServletException: The request content-type is not a multipart/form-data

This code snippet is not in [MVCE flavor](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info), so the cause of the problem is not visible in the information posted so far, but the symptoms at least strongly suggest that the  master template has another `<h:form>` around the `<ui:insert>`. This in turn means that your JSF component tree is ultimately composed as below after Facelets templating has done its job (i.e. when you think away all those `<ui:xxx>` templating tags which are actually irrelevant in this regard):

```
<h:form>
    <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h:inputFile />
    </h:form>
</h:form>
```

A nested form thus. Nesting forms is [illegal](http://validator.w3.org) in HTML. The browser behavior is unspecified. In your particular case, the browser apparently used the outer form to process the POST request. This is not a JSF/Facelets problem. You're yourself responsible that you write JSF code in such way that it produces legal HTML output (which can be seen via rightclick, *View source* in browser). E.g.

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h:inputFile />
</h:form>
<h:form>
    [another content here which requires a form]
</h:form>
```

Comment: Thank you, I got it. And thanks to John for editing.

Comment: I still have to earn reputation to do that.

Comment: Nope, you don't need to earn reputation for accepting answers, only for voting posts. See also the first link in my previous comment.